# Vulnerable JS Library jquery-3.4.1.js reported in Wso2 identity server 5.11.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Vulnerable JS Library jquery-3.4.1.js reported in Wso2 identity server 5.11.0.

I recently installed wso2 identity server 5.11.0 on my linux server and intregrated my application with it.

During ZAP scan below vulnerbaility is reported:

Vulnerable JS Library jquery-3.4.1.js reported in Wso2 identity server 5.11.0

Reported URL :
https://myapplicationurl.com/authenticationendpoint/libs/jquery_3.4.1/jquery-3.4.1.js

Does WSO2 provide any fix for this. It seems the authenticationendpoint application of wso2 uses this js and I am not sure of the impact if I just replace it with higher version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the WSO2 Security reporting process
at https://wso2.com/security. WSO2 discourages discussing security issues in public forums.

Nevertheless, most of the reported vulnerabilities of JQuery are not a threat to WSO2IS when it comes to their usage. Because those vulnerabilities reside in specific functions of JQuery and those functions are not used at all or not used in a vulnerable way.